# CLR Type System

Tags: c#, inheritance, types, clr

I was confused while reading the book "CLR via C#" (Type Fundamentals Chapter), which says that type object of some base type object (for example `class Employee { }`) is **System.Type** and also that GetType method actually returns a pointer to an object's type object (which provides type inheritance), so it sounds like System.Type is the most base type object to which all type objects refer to (and System.Type type pointer refers to itself). But on the other hand, all types are inherited from **System.Object** and in practice, for example, this expression `typeof(Employee).BaseType` returns System.Object (not System.Type!). 
So could anyone explain where the type object pointer actually refers to? System.Type or System.Object?

```
          System.Object
           /         \ 
      Employee     System.Reflection.MemberInfo
                               \
                           System.Type
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to [JonasH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12342238/jonash) who provided the answer. I have also drawn the scheme that helped me to understand it visually:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Have a nice day!:)

Answer (score 1):

> type object of some base type object (for example class Employee { }) is System.Type

This is true, but somewhat confusing, The type object of **any** object is System.Type.

> GetType method actually returns a pointer to an object's type object

Also true. We call it a reference rather than a pointer, but that is a technicality.

> so it sounds like System.Type is the most base type object to which all type objects refer to.

This does not follows the preceding statements. System.Object is the most base object that all other objects derive from. System.Type is an object like any other, so it derives from System.Object. As in your illustration.

Discussions like this can become a bit confusing. It is critical to distinguish between the object type, i.e. `Employee` and the type object for said object i.e. `System.Type`.

Consider it from the language design point of view. It is useful to have a base type that all objects derive from, to allow the programmer to sidestep the typesystem when needed, and have some basic methods like ToString and GetHashcode. It is also useful to let the programmer inspect, and work with the type-system of the language directly. We call this "reflection". System.Type is part of this system, it describes the type information of objects. But it is just like any other type, so it needs to derive from System.Object.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but why it is `Employee -> Type` and not the `Employee -> Object -> Type` ?

Comment: I think you missunderstand. Employee derives from Object, i..e `Employee -> Object`. Each of them has an associated type object, i.e. `typeof(Employee)` or `typeof(Object)`.

Answer (score 0):

[Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate?view=netframework-4.8)

The property BaseType of the Type class returns the class from which the type inherits. So, in the case of System.Delegate, BaseType will be the type System.Object because, if you read the documentation of System.Delegate, it directly inherits from System.Object. Every class in C# inherits from System.Object, even if not directly.

As you can see from the link above, System.Delegate implements ICloneable, System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable. These last two are interfaces, so they don't count as extended classes. So, implicitly, it inherits directly System.Object.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is not related to my question, so I just edited my question description to more clarifying